# Browsers detect my site as There is an issue with this website's security certificate

Tags: windows, iis

I developed a simple php page and installed in iis in my server. I want it to  be available for everyone in the internet.
Then I opened the 443 port,and everyone over the internet is able to visit my page. 
The problem is that all browsers display the following message when accessing to my page:
"There is a problem with this website's security certificate"
What did I do wrong when configuring IIS? How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have a security certificate? You need one that is signed by a major provider for browsers to deem it trust worthy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate

Comment: Did you order your ssl certificate from a trusted root certificate authority?

Comment: If not, you are using a self signed certificate, which cannot be authoritatively trusted... the connection is still encrypted though!

Comment: No I didn't buy a certificate. The only way to stop displaying this error is to buy one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, you need a certificate signed from a trusted source and not locally generated on the server.

You can get a free certificate from the let's encrypt project. There is a popular tool for IIS available at https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple.

Another solution is to buy a certificate. They start from about 4 USD / year and go up from there.

Comment: An addition: Let's encrypt is backed by many big players and usually has better client support than many other free certificates you can find.

Comment: Thanks! I will learn how to use letsencrypt!